# Is it possible to disable publish sha1 and ivy artifacts when use gradle ivy-publish plugin?

Tags: gradle, plugins, publish, ivy, artifact

I try to publish a `rpm` artifact to Nexus repository with gradle plugin ivy-publish (script code written below).  Is it possible to disable publishing some additional artifacts (sha1, ivy files), automatically generated by plugin ivy-publish ?

I've already disabled publishing sha256 and sha512 artifacts with systemProp.org.gradle.internal.publish.checksums.insecure

Gradle version is 6.3.

```
publishing {
  publications {
    artifactDistribution(IvyPublication) {
       module = project.name
       revision = project.version

       def publishingArtifactories = [
            [filename: "build/distributions/${project.name}-${project.version}-${project.release}.i386.rpm", extension: "rpm"],
       ]

       publishingArtifactories.each {
            artifact (it.filename) {
               if (it.extension) {
                  extension it.extension
               }
            }
       }
    }
}

repositories {
    ivy {
        credentials {
            username repoUser
            password repoPassword
        }
        url project.publishUrl
        layout 'pattern', {
           artifact '[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]'
           ivy '[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision].ivy'
           m2compatible = true
        }
    }
}
```

}